# How to send email on certain date with EmailJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email

Trying to use EmailJS with React to try and send automated emails on certain dates. Not sure how to implement this without an EventHandler like onSubmit.

Comment: you should use NodeJS and modules like nodemailer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) to send emails, and node-cron (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) to send automatically at certain moment

Comment: I am trying to implement this part without a backend system and rather than using a exact set date, I will be using a date from user inputted csv files.

Comment: i don't know if you can do it without a backend system, because you can't do an automated task in frontend if i'm not wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to use nodemailer module from npm packages

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).